# Call java collections use an interface of an object instead of the object's class?

Tags: java, collections

I want to call a method using a collection of objects that all implement the same interface. Is this possible?

```
public class GenericsTest {
    public void main() {
        ArrayList<Strange> thisWorks = new ArrayList<>();
        isAllStrange(thisWorks);
        ArrayList<Person> thisDoesNot = new ArrayList<>();
        isAllStrange(thisDoesNot);
    }

    public boolean isAllStrange(ArrayList<Strange> strangeCollection) {
        for (Strange object : strangeCollection) {
            if (object.isStrange())
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public interface Strange {
        public boolean isStrange();
    }

    public class Person implements Strange {
        public boolean isStrange() {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using the `<? extends Interface>` notation:

```
public boolean isAllStrange(List<? extends Strange> strangeCollection) {
    for (Strange object : strangeCollection) {
        if (object.isStrange())
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also, do not use `ArrayList` directly, instead use `List`. More of this:

- [Bounded Type Parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)
- [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197)

Answer (score 1):

Read about [WildCard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html) in Genrics.

You can do this using

```
<? extends Strange >
```